# How to get a view in MVC to properly reference the required model

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

This is the error I'm getting

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WTCoro2.Models.Person]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WTCoro2.Models.PersonViewModel'." but the problem here is that I am using 'WTCoro2.Models.PersonViewModel'

I already tried doing what the error suggests and it's still giving me the same error.

Here is my view:

```
@model WTCoro2.Models.PersonViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Multidata";
}

<h2>Multidata</h2>
<h2>People</h2>
<div>
    @{ WebGrid obj = new WebGrid(source: Model.pers, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);}
    @obj.GetHtml();
</div>
<br />

<h2>Employees</h2>
<div>
    @{ WebGrid obj1 = new WebGrid(source: Model.emp, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);}
    @obj1.GetHtml();
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
// GET: People
public ActionResult Multidata(string sortOrder, string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page, string searchBy, string startdate = null, string enddate = null)
{
    var mymodel = new PersonViewModel();
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    var people_list = mymodel.pers = db.People.ToList();
    var employee_list = db.Employees.ToList();
    var history_list = mymodel.history = db.EmployeeDepartmentHistories.ToList();
    /* if (searchString != null)
     {
         page = 1;
     }
     else
     {
         searchString = currentFilter;
     }
     ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;*/
    searchString = "";
    if (searchBy == "Title")
    {
        return View(employee_list.Where(x => x.JobTitle == searchString || searchString == null).ToList());
    }
    /*  else if (startdate != null && enddate != null)
      {
          DateTime start = DateManager.GetDate(startdate) ?? DateTime.Now;
          DateTime end = DateManager.GetDate(enddate) ?? DateTime.Now;
          return View(history_list.Where(x => x.StartDate >= start && x.EndDate <= end).ToList());

      }*/
    else
    {
        return View(people_list.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(searchString) || x.LastName.StartsWith(searchString) || searchString == null).ToList());
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable <Person> pers { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable <EmployeeDepartmentHistory> history { get; set; }
    public EmployeeDepartmentHistory EmployeeDepartmentHistory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable <Employee> emp { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are not returning your view model from you action method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller returns `IEnumerable<Person>` instead of `PersonViewModel`. Either change in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<WTCoro2.Models.PersonViewModel.pers>
```

or change in the controller:

```
mymodel.pers = (people_list.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(searchString) || x.LastName.StartsWith(searchString) || searchString == null).ToList();

return View(mymodel);
```

Also, please use the proper [naming conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md) (i.e. upper case property names).

Comment: this way works thanks! you have been a real help. Proper naming conventions is a bad habit of mine that I'm trying to get rid off

Answer (score 0):

Yout view expects a PersonViewModel. But you are passing a PersonList.

In your case, you should pass the PersonViewModel.

```
var mymodel = new PersonViewModel();

...

return View(mymodel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your view model in your action method, but you don't return it to your view. Instead you are returning queries from your database to your view, which of course have a different type than your view mode.

So what you want to do is essentially this:

```
public ActionResult Multidata(string sortOrder, string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page, string searchBy, string startdate = null, string enddate = null)
{
    var mymodel = new PersonViewModel();
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    mymodel.pers = db.People.ToList();
    mymodel.emp = db.Employees.ToList();
    mymodel.history = db.EmployeeDepartmentHistories.ToList();
    /* ... */
    if (searchBy == "Title")
    {
        return View(mymodel.Where(x => x.emp.JobTitle == searchString || searchString == null).ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        return View(mymodel.Where(x => x.pers.FirstName.StartsWith(searchString) || x.pers.LastName.StartsWith(searchString) || searchString == null).ToList());
    }
}
```

The key point is in those lines:

```
var people_list = mymodel.pers = db.People.ToList();
```

You are assigning the data from your datasource to your viewmodel and a seperate variable. And then you try to return `people_list`, instead of `mymodel`. 
`people_list` is of type `List<Person>`, while `mymodel` is of type `List<PersonViewModel>`.
The easiest thing to do, is just to get rid of those variables, and simplify it, by just using your viewmodel